# Check the Integrity of Message to an API Response message using JWT-extended in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, flask, flask-restful

Assuming that I have an API endpoint api.example.com/v1/data and a GET method with @jwt-required similar to this:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask_restful import Resource

class Data(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
        """
        GET Response message.
        """
        return {"message":"important-info", "ts":datetime}, 200
```

So to GET this message you need to authenticate yourself with a **Bearer "access_token"** in the request's header.

How could I create an HMAC for this message. Ideally I would like to add the access token, so to check the integrity of the whole message.

So I would like to have an extra field in the returned JSON called checksum with a value hash(whole_message).

Comment: Realistically you should probably just be using https for this. It will be more secure/vetted then anything you come up with on your own, and thanks to tcp you can be sure that your message isn't corrupted over the wire.

Comment: @vimalloc Yes, the request/responses will happen over https. However, I would like to implement this feature, for testing/fun and also interest.

Comment: This one may be worth a shot for reverse engineering/forking. The interesting part for you might be the debug interface to hack around on.   https://github.com/dusktreader/flask-praetorian. Recognizing that this is not an answer but rather just sth related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flask's [`after_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) to register a function that processes the response after it was generated by the view.

For example, to do exactly what you ask for (I am using built-in python's [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function, you can import/write your own as needed):

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    data = json.loads(response.get_data())
    data['checksum'] = hash(response.get_data())
    response.set_data(json.dumps(data))
    return response
```

However, you will have to make sure to always return a dictionary for this to work. Here are a couple alternatives:

1) Include the view's response inside another json, e.g.:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    data = json.loads(response.get_data())
    data = {
        'response': data,
        'checksum': hash(response.get_data())
    }
    response.set_data(json.dumps(data))
    return response
```

2) Add the checksum to the response headers (I would go with this one). E.g.:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers['Checksum'] = hash(response.get_data())
    return response
```

As a final note, if you want to hash the response using the access token, as you state in your question, you can access this token from the `request` object, like so:

```
from flask import request
access_token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
```

So now you can use `access_token` in whatever way you need.